Is there a way to pass a ng-template through another ng-template in angular?
I am running into the issue where I can't pass a nested ng-container in angular.
This is not the exact problem but in general the issue I am running into.
parent.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class Parent {}

parent.component.html
<ng-template #outer>
  <ng-template #inner>Content</ng-template>
</ng-template>

<child>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="outer"></ng-container>
</child>

child.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class Child{
     @ContentChild('inner') inner: TemplateRef<any>;
}

child.component.html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inner"></ng-container>

I would expect the ngTemplateOutlet which loades the outer template to get replaced with the inner one during compilation like this:
<child>
  <ng-template #inner>Content</ng-template>
</child>

...such that the child component would recognize the template ref. This does not seem to happen though.
Any thoughts/ideas to fix this or change my strategy?

As I can check from your code the inner template reference is defined inside the outer template, and Angular's ContentChild in the Child component does not automatically recognize it which is the root cause of the issue.
This can be handled by explicitly passing the inner template reference to the Child component.
Please find the updated code for the files.
parent.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class Parent {
  @ViewChild('inner', { static: true }) innerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}

parent.component.html
<ng-template #outer>
  <ng-template #inner>Content</ng-template>
</ng-template>
<child [innerTemplate]="innerTemplate"></child>

child.component.ts
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class Child {
  @Input() innerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}

child.component.html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="innerTemplate"></ng-container>

Please let me know if this works for you.
